# dummy code multiple columns with same name, including categories not present in data

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dummy-variable

**ADDITIONAL ISSUE**

the columns need to have the actual question appended to the beginning of each column name using a dictionary with the format below. It needs to be accessed in a vectorized way as there are lots of these columns/lists.

dictionary

```
dic = dict({'ab': 'what colour is this?',
     'cd': 'what size is this?',
     'ef': 'who do you live with?'})
```

code

```
dout=[]
for c in df.columns[1:].unique(): #here unique
    b = (pd.get_dummies(df[c], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
           .sum(axis=1, level=0) #here equivalent to groupby.sum
           .reindex(columns = all_categories[c], fill_value=0))
        
    b.columns = [c + ' ' + str(col) for col in b.columns]
    
    for key, value in dic.items():
        b.columns = [col.replace(c, value) for col in b.columns]
        
    dout.append(b)
```

**the below part is SOLVED thanks to @ben.T**

I have a data frame that I want to dummy code - there are multiple columns with the same name, and i also want to include all possible categories in the dummy coded data frame that are not necessarily present in the actual data frame itself.

I can get it working up until i try to incorporate columns from answeres that were not present - I keep getting an error *ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis*

Some similar data is below, and my little code as well (*a* works, *b* doesnt)

Thank you so much!

```
create some data

all_categories = {'ab':  ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'pink', 'None', 
    'orange', 'purple, white'],
                  'cd':  ['XS', 'M', 'L', 'XL'],
                  'ef':  ['husband', 'wife', 'son', 'daughter',
    'grandparent', 'aunt', 'uncle','None'] }

data = {'ab':  ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'None'],
        'ab1': ['red', 'yellow', 'None', 'None'],
        'cd': ['L', 'XL', 'M','L'],
        'ef':['husband', 'wife', 'husband', 'None'],
        'ef1':['son', 'grandparent', 'son', 'None'],
        'ef2':['None', 'son', 'None', 'None'] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ab', 'ab1', 'cd', 'ef', 'ef1', 'ef2'])
df = df.rename(columns={'ab1':'ab', 'ef1':'ef', 'ef2':'ef'})
```

```
command

dout=[]
for c in df.columns[1:]:
    a = pd.concat([df['id'], pd.get_dummies(df[c], prefix='', prefix_sep='')],axis=1) ### this works  
    b = pd.get_dummies(df[c], prefix='', prefix_sep='').reindex(columns = all_categories, fill_value=0) ### this does not work 
    dout.append(b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, as you have duplicated columns name, you could loop over `unique` columns name. For the problem with `reindex`, you can first use `sum` along columns (axis=1) and use level=0 to perform a groupby similar columns name.

```
dout=[]
for c in df.columns[1:].unique(): #here unique
    b = (pd.get_dummies(df[c], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
           .sum(axis=1, level=0) #here equivalent to groupby.sum
           .reindex(columns = all_categories[c], fill_value=0)
        )
    dout.append(b)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ben.T  that worked perfectly! and made me realise I have another issue which i have updated the question with

Comment: @br101 you can simply chain the `reindex` with `.add_prefix(f'{dic[c]} ')` so it makes `b=( ... reindex(...).add_prefix(f'{dic[c]} '))` and should be good. you can also look at multiindex columns, because here it could be a good use case for it